# Проверка списка на соответствие

Tags: python

Есть список, в который добавляются записи. Как сделать, чтобы при добавлении новой записи в этот список происходила проверка на присутствие похожей записи в списке. И если похожая запись есть в этом списке, то новая, какая еже не добавляется.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему. Например, что вам мешает сделать эту проверку перед добавлением записи в список?

Comment: В общем случае примерно так `if item not in lst: lst.append(item)`

Comment: Используйте множества, если порядок элементов не важен

Comment: А что значит "похожая"? Такая же, или почти, но не совсем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант номер РАЗ:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 2]
b = []
for item in a:
    if item not in b:
        b.append(item)

print(b)  # [1, 2]
```

Вариант ДВА:

```
a = [1, 2, 1, 2]
b = set(a)
print(b)  # {2, 1}
```

Вариант ТРИ (если порядок следования элементов нужно сохранить):

```
a = [2, 1, 1, 2]
b = sorted(set(a), key=lambda x: a.index(x))
print(b)  # [2, 1]
```